# How to do pagination in datagridview when columns added manually?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to do pagination in datagridview, there are so much methods but they are for if direct binding data from database. Can anyone tell how to do pagination when we add columns manually

Comment: Do you mean you want to print page numbers? Or are you talking about screen pages, which will change whenever the DGV gets resized??

Answer (score 0):

To add paging you need to know the total rows that are coming from your data, then split these up into pages, and populate the datagridview's datasource, then you can handled how the columns display.

For a fuller example for paging see Sk Saini's Code Project article [A Simple Way for Paging in DataGridView in WinForm Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/211551/A-Simple-way-for-Paging-in-DataGridView-in-WinForm) from which I have based a lot of this answer on.

So using BindlingList for example, and bearing in mind this is an incomplete solution.

```
private int pageSize = 10;
private int currentPage = 0;
private int totalPages;
private BindlingList<object> bindinglist;

public void InitialiseDataSource(){

    // populate bindinglist..
    bindinglist = new Bindlist<object>(){etc..}

    CalculateTotalPages();

    SetDataSource(1);
}

private void CalculateTotalPages(){

    int rowCount = bindingList.Count;

    this.totalPages = rowCount / this.pageSize;

    if (rowCount % this.pageSize > 0){
       this.totalPage += 1;
    }
}

private int GetNumOfItemsToShow(int page){
    return this.pageSize * this.page;
}

private int GetNumOfItemsToSkip(){
    return this.pageSize * this.currentPage;
}
```

This method would be different if you were using some other type of datasource, but for our BindingList, work out how many items to skip and how many you want to show:

```
private void SetDataSource(int page){

    var itemsToSkip = GetNumOfItemsToSkip();
    var itemsToShow = GetNumOfItemsToShow(page);

    var listToShow = bindingList.Skip(itemsToSkip).Take(itemsToShow);

    this.currentPage = page;

    dataGridView1.DataSource =  listToShow;
}
```

Then to move pages between pages add in methods for NextPage, PreviousPage etc..

```
private void NextPage(){

  var page = currentPage + 1;

  if (page <= totalPages){
      SetDataSource(page);   
  } else {
      //do something else
  }
}
```